# Manage gestures in iPhone IOS 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I'm using UIGesturerecognizer to handle gesture (swipes, taps, double taps etc.) in my app.

In a device with IOS 3.1.2. We tried the app but most of the gestures simply don't respond, ina ll of our devices with recent IOS like 4.1 the app works perfectly. Seems like UIGestureRecognizer can't use that strategy to handle gestures, since it was added in the SDK 3.2. So:

- Will have to handle myself gestures such as swipes, pinchs, counter pinchs, pans, double taps from multiple fingers with methods such as touchesEnded:withEvent, touchesMoved:withEvent: etc. If i want my app to work in the IOS 3.1.2?
- It's more reasonable to ignore the IOS 3.1.2 and require my customers to upgrade their firmware ?, or it's logical to ditch the use of UIGesturerecognizer and implement the gestures myself.
- It's out there a free library o resource to help me detect those gestures in the IOS 3.1.2 without UIGestureRecognizer ?
- I'm using the latest SDK, and i only can test for IOS 4.1 and IOS 3.2. How can test my app for the  IOS 3.1.2 ?, or configure my simulator to work with this IOS ?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 I've hit the same question, except that I don't have *yet* used UIGestureRecognizer, since I had only simple single-touch features.

Answer (score 0):

I test iOS 3.1.2 with an iPhone, which is installed with iOS 3.1.2.
I don't like to be compatible with iOS 3.1.2 at all. It contains many bugs. If you want to be compatible with iOS 3.1.2, you must have an iPhone which installed an old version iOS.

Comment: This is not necessarily true - if you have a device that does not support iOS 4 (such as the original iPhone or iPod touch), then you are at the maximum supported version for your device.